# We going to have a hair cut

Tags: grammar

My son's hair and I are long.

I decided to take him to barber shop.

"Where are we going?" he asked.

> "We going to have a hair cut."
>
> "We going to get a hair cut."

I said.

Do they sound natural? Before hair cut, we should use have or get?

Comment: You're missing an auxiliary verb: `we ARE going to ...`. Other than that, and the fact that `haircut` is spelled as one word, at least in British English they're both fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's a "haircut".  If you got a hair cut, that would be *one* hair being cut.  (My mother is addicted to inane wordplay; if you were to ask if she got a haircut, she would certainly respond, "No, I got them all cut.")

Usually, when purchasing a service, an English speaker prefers "have".  "I am having my car painted."  "I had a kidney removed." *Get* sounds very informal in that context.

But when the service is expressed as an ordinary noun, it becomes much more like purchasing a product and *get* suddenly becomes popular.  "I am getting a new paint job for my car." "I got a kidney transplant."

So,

"I am having my hair styled."

*but*

"I am getting a haircut."